# Insecure file location is retrieved via getExternalMediaDirs - AppSweep issue

Tags: android, flutter, dexguard, appsweep

I am integrating Appsweep on my Flutter Application. I have the following issue: getExternalMediaDirs is not secure as any application can contribute new media to MediaStore without any permission. How can I solve this issue? I am not directly using this method, so I couldn't find it in my project. [Image attached] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U2GR.png)

I have also integrated DexGuard, but couldn't found any solution for this issue.

Comment: Unclear what you find unsecure. And you also did not explain what getExternalMediaDirs() has to do with adding files some where by using MediaStore.

Comment: This is the issue found by AppSweep. I have attached also an image

Comment: You might post your own considerations and fears as what are you expecting of us?

Comment: I am not using getExternalMediaDirs() method directly, so I don't know how can I solve this issue found by AppSweep.

Comment: What do you want to solve? And why? What is your problem? Tell us! Tell why it concerns you.

Comment: I want to solve all the issues displayed by AppSweep after I upload my android apk and this is one of the issues. And I can't find any solution for it, so my question is if anybody solved the above issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

the quickest way to get answers for AppSweep related issues is to use the chatbot on the bottom right of the AppSweep page. Then you can talk to someone from the team directly, and we can help directly on the scan.

For the specific issue:
The Flutter SDK seems to contain a call to `getExternalMediaDirs`. This method is deprecated (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalMediaDirs()).
If your app does not use any local storage to such folders, it could be ok, but to be sure, you'd need to figure out where Flutter actually uses this folder.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was from the open_file package.